# Store parent key from firebase into arraylist and print out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Sample]

The keys shown in the image are user's UID. I am trying to store those keys to arraylist and check if currentuser's UID is not in the arraylist but the result is failed as println does not show anything.

```py
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Dentist");
        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    list1.add(child.getKey());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list1.get(i));
        }
if (!list1.contains(user.getUid())) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()` is an Asynchronous listener , if you will check `list1` inside `onDataChange` you will get the results

Comment: @BenShmuel Solved.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

as stated before, your are performing an asynchronous task.
You're checking if the list contains your user while your list might be at that moment empty.

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Dentist");
        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                   list1.add(child.getKey());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                   System.out.println(list1.get(i));
               }
               if (!list1.contains(user.getUid())) {
                  //do something
               }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```